# Why my javascript is not enabling the button?

Tags: javascript

I have a code to delete a record from my database, but for that I have to put a password, so I blocked the button so that nobody can click it, but when I put the password I can't release the button, how can I solve this? This is my code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["id"]) && !empty($_POST["id"])){
    require_once "config.php";
    
    $sql = "DELETE FROM crud WHERE id = ?";
    
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $param_id);
        
        $param_id = trim($_POST["id"]);
        
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            header("location: index.php");
            exit();
        } else{
            echo "Oops! Algo deu errado. Por favor tente mais tarde.";
        }
    }
     
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    
    mysqli_close($link);
} else{
    if(empty(trim($_GET["id"]))){
        header("location: error.php");
        exit();
    }
}
?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Top Services</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        .wrapper{
            width: 1250px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="page-header">
                        <h1>Top Services</h1>
                        <hr>
                        <h2>Deletar Serviços</h2>
                    </div>
                    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
                        <div class="alert alert-danger fade in">
                            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo trim($_GET["id"]); ?>"/>
                            <p>Você tem certeza que deseja deletar esse serviço?</p><br>
                            <p>

                                <input type="text" name="pass" id="pass" class="form-control" onkeyup="validate()"></br>
                                <input type="submit" value="Sim" class="btn btn-danger" disabled="true">
                                <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-default">Não</a>
                            </p>
                            
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
<script>

$(document).ready(function (){
    validate();
    $('#pass').change(validate);
});

function validate(){
    if ($('#pass').val() == "1234") {
        $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", false);
    }
    else {
        $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", true);
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is the javascript that i am using:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function (){
    validate();
    $('#pass').change(validate);
});

function validate(){
    if ($('#pass').val() == "1234") {
        $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", false);
    }
    else {
        $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", true);
    }
}
</script>
```

so i need help to know why my button is not being enabled, i dont know what is going on.

just in case i'm going to put the main page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Top Services</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .wrapper{
            width: 1250px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .page-header h2{
            margin-top: 0;
        }
        table tr td:last-child a{
            margin-right: 15px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="page-header clearfix">
                        <h2 class="pull-left">Top Services</h2>
                        <a href="create.php" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Adicionar novo serviço</a>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    require_once "config.php";
                    
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM crud";
                    if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
                        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                            echo "<table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>";
                                echo "<thead>";
                                    echo "<tr>";
                                        echo "<th>#</th>";
                                        echo "<th>Cliente</th>";
                                        echo "<th>Número do Pedido</th>";
                                        echo "<th>WhatsApp</th>";
                                        echo "<th>Status Pedido</th>";
                                        echo "<th>Data de Entrega</th>";
                                        echo "<th>Total Mdf Branco</th>";
                                        echo "<th>Total Madeirado</th>";
                                        echo "<th>Total Peças</th>";
                                        echo "<th>Total de Fita de Borda</th>";
                                        echo "<th>Progresso</th>";
                                        echo "<th>Observações</th>";
                                        echo "<th>Finalização do Serviço;</th>";
                                    echo "</tr>";
                                echo "</thead>";
                                echo "<tbody>";
                                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                                    echo "<tr>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['cliente'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['pedido'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['whatsapp'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['statusPedido'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['dataEntrega'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['totalBranco'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['totalMadeirado'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['totalPecas'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['totalFitas'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['progresso'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['observacao'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['finalizacao'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>";
                                            echo "<a href='read.php?id=". $row['id'] ."' title='Ver Serviços' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'></span></a>";
                                            echo "<a href='update.php?id=". $row['id'] ."' title='Atualizar Serviços' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a>";
                                            echo "<a href='delete.php?id=". $row['id'] ."' title='Deletar Serviços' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a>";
                                        echo "</td>";
                                    echo "</tr>";
                                }
                                echo "</tbody>";                            
                            echo "</table>";
                            mysqli_free_result($result);
                        } else{
                            echo "<p class='lead'><em>Sem serviços encontrados.</em></p>";
                        }
                    } else{
                        echo "ERROR: Não foi possível executar $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
                    }
 
                    mysqli_close($link);
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where have you included jQuery?

Comment: is in a other file, index.php, this is the delete.php, this project is a CRUD

Comment: As long as you include it before you use it… I don’t see jQuery included anywhere.

Comment: i'm a beginner, sorry i really forgot to put it on, it helped me than you

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to include jQuery to your html-page:

jQuery is a javascript library that you use in your code in constructs like:

```
$('#pass').val()
```

An example of connection jQuery is to write the following code in the :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

After connecting jquery, your code works.
https://jquery.com/download/